# Error in my taglib <%@ taglib prefix="portlet" uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0"%>

Tags: eclipse, portlet, taglib

When I developed my portlet and when i wrote my jsp page I used:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="portlet" uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0"%>
```

but eclipse show me an error telling me that it **cannot find the tag lib descriptor for http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0.**

How can I resolve this issue wihtout using tld files ?

Comment: Why don't you want to have the required tld file on your project? Is your project working if you deploy your portlet?

Comment: I want just using portlet 2.0 specification without need of liferay tld file , i haven't yet deploy it

Comment: Where is the .tld for that URI?

Comment: See this answer: [Add the javax.portlet.portlet-api dependency][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15992545/188453

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I am using Liferay Portal, so in order to avoid this error
I changed:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0"% prefix="portlet">
```

to

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/liferay-portlet.tld" prefix="portlet" %>
```

and in file **"WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.properties"**;  I added this line

```
portal-dependency-tlds=/WEB-INF/tld/liferay-portlet.tld
```

which is suggested by a Liferay staff ([Link](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4899348))

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0"% prefix="portlet">
```

and paste this line:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" prefix="portlet"%>
```

Then, in `WEB-INF/tld` folder put these files: `aui.tld`, `liferay-portlet.tld`, `liferay-portlet-ext.tld`, `liferay-security.tld`, `liferay-theme.tld`, `liferay-ui.tld`, `liferay-util.tld`.

Answer (score 1):

You can download [portlet-2.0.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadportlet20jar.htm) and add it to your project path. But if you are developping for Liferay I would recommand you to use the `liferay-portlet.tld` which has the portlet 2.0 specification.

Answer (score 1):

If you add this to the web.xml in the WEB-INF folder it will remove the Eclipse error message.

```
<web-app>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/liferay-portlet.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</web-app>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This error just means that Eclipse is unable to find a tag library descriptor (TLD) that resolves the given (http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0) tag URI. You can download the TLD corresponding to your portal container (Gatein, Pluto, Liferay, etc) from GitHub and place it in WEB-INF folder. Gatein specific tld can be found [here](https://github.com/gatein/gatein-pc/blob/master/portlet/src/main/resources/META-INF/portlet_2_0.tld).
Also, make sure that you have the portlet_2.0 jar in your project path.