# Maven Dependency for Spring and Portlet tags

Tags: java, spring, netbeans, taglib, spring-portlet-mvc

I have this following problem in Netbeans IDE - when I create a JSP file and put these two taglibs inside

```
<%@taglib prefix="portlet" uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" %> 
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

then I get error `The absolute uri ... cannot be resolved`. So I am wondering where could be the problem?Application is working correctly when is deployed to AS but I would like to enjoy things like autocompletion during development. My `pom.xml` looks like this - [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/nEb8tw0q).

I suppose I have all the necessary JARs on classpath so how can I make NetBeans to recognize those tags?

Comment: Have you found the way how to fix it?

Comment: I am afraid I didn't - but this is year ago and I am doing something else right now so I don't really remember :)

Answer (score 1):

To fix the portlet TLD problem add this to your POM

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The scope of provided is important - bear in mind you just want this to be included for validating in your IDE. The portlet TLD will be provided by whichever JSR-286 implementation you are deploying to e.g. Liferay, uPortal etc.

NB this worked for me in Eclipse, I presume it will also do the trick in NetBeans.

Comment: It is not working for me, I have this dependency in my project since beginning.

Answer (score 0):

To use sprint tags it enough to declare one spring dependency

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Spring downloads other dependencies automatically. All dependency list for spring portlet you can see [here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/spring-webmvc-portlet/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-portlet-3.2.1.RELEASE.pom)

With portlet tags a little more complicated, I still can't find dependency for portlet taglib and I always copy portlet_2_0.tld to my WEB-INF/tld folder, if you find this dependency let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I already have this dependency in my pom.xml. So I suspect it is going to be Netbeans related problem.

Comment: Does NetBEans have any way of turning off jsp validations? Eclipse has that....turning off validations may help make the error go away

Comment: Yes, when I turned it off, the error disappears. But the think is that I would like to use to autocomplete feature which is not working now.