# how to solve jsp error?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, liferay

hello i m new in jsp i got the error in jsp page
while i put following code in top of the file.

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
```

i got following error.

> Can not find the tag library descriptor for
>   `"http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0"`

i am using liferay eclipse ide.
creating form using jsp page and i got the error in top of the file.
i have created init.jsp file and in that file i have put all common stuff in it. and i got error in init.jsp file

hello i am also providing u my init.jsp file.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@page import="javax.portlet.PortletURL"%>
<%@page import="javax.portlet.ActionRequest"%>
<%@page import="javax.portlet.ActionResponse" %>
<%@ page import="com.dir.service.directoryLocalServiceUtil" %>
<%@ page import="com.dir.model.directory" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />
```

i got the error in first line.
**Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0"**

Comment: What error you are getting??

Comment: Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0"

Comment: Possible Duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991799/error-in-my-taglib-taglib-prefix-portlet-uri-http-java-sun-com-portlet

Comment: above error i got. how to solve it? should i add my init.jsp here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a web.xml to your WEB-INF folder with the following content should help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.5//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

<taglib>
<taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0</taglib-uri>
<taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/liferay-portlet.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>

</web-app>
```

Comment: <display-name>directory-portlet</display-name>
 
 <jsp-config>
  <taglib>
   <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0</taglib-uri>
   <taglib-location>
    /WEB-INF/tld/liferay-portlet.tld
   </taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <taglib>
   <taglib-uri>http://liferay.com/tld/aui</taglib-uri>
   <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/aui.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  
  <taglib>
<taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0</taglib-uri>
<taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/liferay-portlet.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
 </jsp-config>
 
 
</web-app>
 this is my file still got the error n init.jsp

Comment: here i m giving you my "init.jsp" i got error in first line. kindly help me.
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

    <%@page import="javax.portlet.PortletURL"%>
    <%@page import="javax.portlet.ActionRequest"%>
    <%@page import="javax.portlet.ActionResponse" %>

    <%@ page import="com.dir.service.directoryLocalServiceUtil" %>

    <%@ page import="com.dir.model.directory" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
    <portlet:defineObjects />

Comment: You need to create the web.xml with the necessary tld's to resolve this issue.Hope u have portlet-container.jar

Comment: at which location i should find portlet-container.jar?

Comment: In your eclipse buildpath. You can google that and it have the META-INF where the tld's are to be defined.If you don't have this jar download that.

Comment: add the jar file in eclipse build path.And google would help u better

Comment: yes i would like to move to chat but i dont have enough reputation because i am new. thats why i have to put comment over here

Comment: hello vignesh vino.. i have already web.xml in my tomcat/webapps/root/web-inf/web.xml should  if change in it? kindly help me i am confuse